# Testing result multiply add subtract divide possible for set of numbers

Tags: c++, c

I want to know if in any combination, integers A B C D is able to make integer RESULT.

For example, lets say I have 4, 6, 5, 11 and the result I need is 40

The program will (great if it could test intelligently) brute force through all the options is fine, it could see how the numbers can make 40.

For example, the program will do

4 + 6 + 5 + 11 is 40? no

4 + 6 + 5 - 11 is 40? no

4 + 6 - 5 - 11 is 40? no

....

4 * 6 / 5 / 11 is 40? no

4 * 6 + 5 + 11 is 40? yes

Then it can display 4 * 6 + 5 + 10 gives you the result you want.

How can I make a program do this? something like

```
for(x = 0; x < 4; x++) // four nested for loops
    if(x == 0)
        first mathematics sign = multiply
        ....
    if(x == 3) 
        first mathematics sign = subtract
    if(y == 0)
        second mathematics sign = multlply
```

might work right? but how do I do the set mathematic sign for future calculations bit.

Thanks!

Comment: Search for permutation which relates to the act of arranging elements. Here, you have four operations (i.e. +-*/) and you need to use only three of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive *Brute-Force* implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

int reverseOp(char oper, int x, int y)
{
 switch (oper)
  {
    case '+': return y - x; 
    case '-': return y + x;
    case '*': return y/x;
    case '/': return y * x;
    default: assert(false);
  }
}
std::array<char, 4> ops {'+', '-', '*', '/'};

std::vector<int> trunc(const std::vector<int>& vect, int i)
{ std::vector<int> v(vect);
  v.erase(v.begin()+i);
  return std::move(v);
}

bool findCombination(const std::vector<int>& vect, int target, std::ostringstream& path)
{
  if(vect.size() == 1)
  { if(vect[0] == target) path << vect[0];
    return vect[0] == target;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < ops.size(); ++j) if(ops[j] != '*' || target % vect[i] == 0)
    { bool found = findCombination(trunc(vect, i), reverseOp(ops[j], vect[i], target), path);
      if (found)
      { path << ops[j] << vect[i];
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{ std::vector<int> vect {4, 6, 5, 11};
  std::ostringstream path;
  bool found = findCombination(vect, 40, path);
  if(found) std::cout << "Found: " << path.str() << "\n";
  else std::cout << "Not found\n";

  system("pause"); return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> Found: 11-5*6+4

Notice: the output is not a representation of the expression in the sense of operator precedence; it just operates from left to right.

It's just a fast implementation and sure, nobody will use it in a real scernario because it's very slow for large sets, it is, as you requested, *"brute force".*

Comment: Hey there, I'm wondering what I need to #include and such in order to make the code compile. It's popping up with a million pages of errors when I try to compile it.

Comment: @Friedpanseller please try this last version, including the necessary `#include`, and better dealing with the integer division case. Also note that this supposes that we *have to* include each of the numbers in the result, once and only once. Is that what you wanted? I could not have the answer from the problem's statement.

Comment: Yep that's perfect! Thank you!

Comment: I did notice when testing it that it can't do calculations that need brackets like 13 10 10 2, 13 - (10 / 10) + 2 = 24 but since the program can only do one calculation at once it returns Not Found

Comment: Yeah, I admit. Hey, subgrouping parenthesized expressions was not part of the deal :P